# Firefox Portable (multi instance) won't load its profile if other Firefox already open

Tags: firefox, windows-11, portable-apps, firefox-profile

I have a strange problem. I have three instances of Firefox Portable (on a Windows 11 system). I did set the option `AllowMultipleInstances=true` in the `FirefoxPortable.ini` file and for the first few weeks, everything worked fine. I use the first FF is my main browser which is always open. From time to time I need one of the two other FF browsers.

Then suddenly the second FF won't load its profile anymore when the first FF is already open. It just loads the profile from the open first FF. Only after I close the first FF it can load its own profile. The third browser works fine.

The same thing happens if I load the third FF browser first, then the second FF browser loads the profile from the open third FF.

Does anyone have any idea how to find the cause or how to fix it? The first searches on SU and regular search engines didn't give me any clues (so far).

**Edit:**
I found additional hints / a workaround:

- Install a new portable Firefox
- Copy the Profile from the faulty FF and replace the profile of the new FF

So it should have s.th. to do with the "regular" FF program files. I'm still looking for the cause of the problem, please feel free to post an answer if you know the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

- Install a new portable Firefox
- Copy the profile from the faulty FF and replace the profile of the new FF

Sometimes I can reproduce the error by copying an existing Firefox Portable Program folder. If I do this, both versions the original and the copy won't load their profile anymore. So far I could not identify the exact cause of the problem so I accepted the workaround as an answer for now.

But I'm still looking for the cause of the problem, please feel free to post an answer if you know the actual cause. I'll be happy to change the accepted answer.